# When I click on the button, I have two output instead of one output

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I am a beginner in Python. I should realize a project (bank management with tkinter). When I click on the button, I get two output instead of one output. Can you tell me where my error is?

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.nom1 = StringVar()
        self.v = ""
        self.creer_widgets()
        self.compte = 0


    def creer_widgets(self):
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text = "Compte Banquaire")
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = self.nom1)
        self.bouton=tk.Button(self, text = "Entrer", command = lambda: Gestion.gest_nom(self))

        self.v = self.nom1.get()
        self.label.pack()
        self.entry.pack()
        self.bouton.pack()

    def connaitre(self):
        print(self.nom1.get())

class Gestion(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def gest_nom(self):
        a = Application.connaitre(self)
        print(a)
     

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

I get the output:

```
10000
None
```

Comment: `connaitre` prints a value but returns nothing (which implicitly returns `None`). The returned `None` is then printed in `gest_nom`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the "connaitre" function. You are *printing* the value, not actually returning it. So when the "gest_com" function references the "conntaitre" function, it is running the code in the function, but not getting any return value. So the value of variable "a" is equal to "None". What you should do is say:

```
return self.nom1.get()
```

instead of

```
print (self.nom1.get())
```

Hope this helps.